# Deploy NodeJs app with and without hosting services

Tags: node.js, express

I wanted to know how could I deploy a Nodejs Express web on my own pc/enterpsise server (windows 10 preferable, but not a must) without hosting services and opened to the world (not localhost) and if the free hosting alternatives like heroku, Openshift or opennode could be eficient for something like e-comerce or CRM.

Is important in my case to know both methods (own pc and external hosting)

Comment: complete docs for heroku at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs.  u should be able to find/follow example with all details u would need. RE: ecomm  .. IMO they are just 3rd party API calls and if u take care w/ CORS issues and u follow examples , they will just work on hosted solution such as heroku.

Comment: Hi thanks. I found that documentation before, but Heroku have many important limits that Probably will be a problem in my case such as 1000 rows db limit and sleeping time. Lots of people recomend Heroku, but not for prod. Probably opennode could have less limitations, but I don't know if is enougth for made those kind of web aplications. Heroku is expenssive on higher tiers/plans than others like  openshift, opennode.io and DigitalOcean, but I don't know if is better or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Local Tunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) which will point your localhost to subdomain.localtummel.me

you have option to set custom subdomain, by default it chooses a random subdomain

Comment: Thanks I'll investigate about Local tunnel. I found some docs about Zenit Now and p2m but It havent't a really free solution.  This method seems to work for showing demos or similar and probaly some of the others paid hosting methods for production, because it apears that the free hosting not to be enough for prod (real prod environment of medium enterpsise)